# How to solve the pie-donut chart tooltip transparent without using any css?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

[image: How to solve the below image tooltip transparent issue fix. Without using z-index and any seperate css.]

How to solve the above image tooltip transparent issue fix? Without using z-index and any seperate css?
We are using 4.0.1 version. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you hiring a developer here? Didn't notice the payments.

Comment: You can disable useHTML flag in tooltip, can you recraete your issue as live demo on jsfiddle.net? Why you cannot use a CSS?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fuyhjmp1/4/
Is there any highchart property available?
If not i will choose the css option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a CSS styles:

```
.highcharts-container {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
.MyChartTooltip {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50;
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 108, 169);
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
```

and edit tooltip:

```
tooltip: {
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: false,
        formatter: function () {
            return '<div class="MyChartTooltip"><span class="ag-title">' + this.key + ' &#40;' + this.percentage.toFixed(0) + '&#37;&#41;</span><br/> <span><span style="font-size:25px">' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0) + '</span> myTickets</span></div>';
        },
        useHTML: true,
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fuyhjmp1/5/

Answer (score 0):

[`tooltip`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip) has a property `backgroundColor`. Set it to `transparent` and that should do it.

> **backgroundColor: Color**
>   The background color or gradient for the tooltip. Defaults to rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85).

```
tooltip: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
}
```

Working **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuyhjmp1/)**